# Could golang implement this interview question of getting array summary without for/while if/else?

Tags: c++, loops, go, if-statement

I'm looking into an interesting interview question, and try to implement it with go.

> (1) Input an integer number, say `i`

> (2) Calculate the summary of `1+2+...+i`, output the summary

> (3) Requirement: don't use multiply, don't use loop(`for/while`), and don't use `if/else`

Well, in c++ or java this is pretty easy. We can use static variable to initialize an object array, while the objects's constructor function calculate this summary. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
struct s {
    static int count;
    static int sum;
    s() {++count; sum += count;}
};
int s::count = 0;
int s::sum = 0;
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   s obj[10];
   std::cout << s::sum << std::endl; // 55, ok
   return 0;
}
```

(2) in c++ we could also use template type deduction to do this. Plenty samples on the internet.

But, can we achieve this with go language?

I know that golang has neither constructor function, nor it supports static variable. And it doesn't have any template syntax. Plus, using recursive function still requires `if` branches in the code.

So is this possible to do same thing in go? (no for loop, no if else). Thanks.

Comment: Your c++ solution wouldn't work for a user input `i`, I'd imagine the interview question was looking for just printing [`i*(i+1)/2`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Comment: The sum can be evaluated algebraically without doing any summing. This is a _math_ problem, not a _programming_ problem. The second you try to "solve" this with clever "programming" you failed.

Comment: Try `fmt.Println(i*(i+1)/2)`, no sum, no cleverness, basically the same in _any_ language.

Comment: This is also a very questionable interview question that essentially asks whether somebody is ready to misuse language constructs when solving problems. Are they trying to hire the person who can write the most unmaintainable code?

Comment: I forgot to mention: requirement 1 includes: don't use multiply

Comment: Here's a language-neutral solution that uses no multiplication, no `for`, no `if`: https://go.dev/play/p/XUNeLPNceWt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a language-neutral solution that uses no multiplication, no `for` and no `if`.

It's kind of like a recursive solution, where the `if` is substituted with a function map, having functions for the `true` and `false` branches:

```
fs := map[bool]func(int) int{}
fs[false] = func(int) int { return 0 }
fs[true] = func(i int) int { return i + fs[i > 1](i-1) }

var i int
fmt.Scanln(&i)

fmt.Println("sum:", fs[i > 0](i))
```

Inputting `10`, the output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XUNeLPNceWt)):

```
sum: 55
```

Comment: This answer is great!